# pip on a Mininet host cant find installed packages

Tags: python, pip, mininet

I have [Mininet](http://mininet.org/) on a VM, I installed a package called `wsproto` using `pip`, but when I try to use that package from inside a Mininet host I get an error indicating that the package is missing:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/http3_server.py", line 10, in <module>
    import wsproto
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsproto'
```

It turns out that the packages available for the Mininet host are far less than the packages actually installed on the system!

**My Question:**
How do I install a Python package and make it available for Mininet?

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04, using Python 3.8.10:

```sh
$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python3 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

and on Mininet:

```
h1 whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python3 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution, I had to use `sudo` like so:

```sh
sudo pip install wsproto
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the string `user.type` with an unknown variable `fetus` , you should compare it with the string `'fetus'` not with `fetus`

```
<div *ngIf="user.type=='fetus'">
```